# Extend Devise form validations to custom user form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using the Devise gem to handle my app authentication and have added some custom features allowing the administrator role to ADD/EDIT users.

To enable these features I have an additional form in my users view which is used for the custom NEW/EDIT methods.

Is there a way I can easily extend the Devise native validations to this custom form or should I just recreate these validations in my user model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your own validations in your user model. The Devise wiki has a little info on this:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-custom-email-validator-with-Devise

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-user-account-status-validation-when-logging-in